# Code to filter according to number value in csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I was wondering if someone could help me. I am trying to see positive and negative correlations in a dataset. This dataset has 3 columns (although the third can be disregarded) and is in a csv format. The first column (called "Feature") indicates the gene of interest (e.g. TP53) and the second column (called "Correlation") indicates  a correlation value (e.g. 0.11123141425532467).

I was trying to make a code on google colaboratory which would:

1. Tell me if the correlation is positive (>0.95) or negative (<-0.95) or no correlation.
2. Let me filter which genes I would like to test for these correlations.

Any resources or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I tried doing things like this:
dataPositiveCorr=df[df.Correlation>0.95]
dataPositiveCorr

but it wouldn't show all of the different genes and didn't show decimals. Moreover, I couldn't filter the specific genes I wanted to see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `df[(df.Correlation>0.95) & (df. Feature=="TP53")]`

Answer (score 0):

If the Panda Kim's answear is what you are looking for, you can show your decimal number adding this line code:

```
df.round({'Correlations': 17})
```